# Two passports one with J1 visa

Tags: visas, usa, study, j1-visas

I am currently studying masters in the US and I posses two passports one of which has a J1 visa.

I would like to continue my PhD in the same university I am currently enrolled in as soon as I finish my masters degree, but as my J1 visa is not extendable, can I apply for an F1 student visa using my second passport, and can I do it while I am still in the US?

Comment: Your passport does not have a visa, you have a visa. Trying to get round the system by using a second passport will cause you much more trouble if it is discovered.

Comment: @DJClayworth How will they know?!

Comment: Because your name, birth date and other personal details are the same on both passports. Their computer system will find out. And while you might get away with it, one possible outcome of being caught is being accused of immigration fraud, deported and permanently denied entry to the US.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to apply for any US visa whilst you are in the US.

All applications must be made in person at a US embassy/consulate outside of the US, so even having a second passport is not going to help you here.  Further, your new status only starts once you re-enter the country using the new visa.

Under certain circumstances it is possible to apply for a "Change of Status" whilst you are in the US, however I would be fairly certain that a change from J1 to F1 would not be allowed.

Comment: There are some exceptions.  My wife has a G-4 visa and she routinely applies for and receives a new visa in the US.